# Holding position of a lable on a form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, label

I create a form and set a picture as it background(pic1).
[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eb3Sq.jpg)

as you can see I put a label between Braces.
But when I run the app (in full screen mode) the label is stay in its Previous position.(pic2)

[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0i7xv.png)

I want that picture wrap between braces when I run the app(In full screen mode)

Comment: Do you want it to have the same position compared to the right? (so if 10px left from the right edge, after resize it will still be) Then user `anchor` set it to `right` and `bottom` and it will move when you resize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `Anchor` property of textbox.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

in proprieties windows you can find Anchor. it works really strange i can say,but you can play with it for few minutes and you will get it. doesn't work as expected i can say,but this is the only way. 
here's a video that might help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xIDZTrYTu-0

Comment: @jordan try to explain how it works don't just link to youtube video because the link may die sometimes in the future